# jquery click and minus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem.....

when clicking on .aa it makes the elements and with the help of `seattist['seats'][column][row]['price']` counts the price and shows the general price in `$(".checkout_area")`

there is a `$(".desc2 a")` button in each, and when clicking on it, it should subtract the `seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price']` from the general price and show it in the `$(".checkout_area")`, I've written it there, but I don't know why, it doesn't work...

have any suggestions.
thank you

```
    var ipl = 1;
    var price = 0;
    var createNewElem = function(obj) {
        var column = obj.parent().children().index(obj.get(0));
        var row = obj.parent().parent().children().index(obj.get(0).parentNode);
        ++ipl;

        if (!$(obj.attr("rel")) || $(obj.attr("rel")).size() < 1) {
            obj.attr("rel", "#cc_" + ipl);
            $(".seat_desc")
                .append("<div id='cc_" + ipl + "' class='desc2'>" +
                "<p class='section_s'>" + seatlist['seats'][column][row]['sector'].replace(/sector\s/, '') + "</p>" +
                "<p class='row_r'>" + seatlist['seats'][column][row]['row'].replace(/Row\s/, '') + "</p>" +
                "<p class='seat_s'>" + seatlist['seats'][column][row]['seat'].replace(/seat\s/, '') + "</p>" +
                "<a href='#'>remove</a>" +
                "<span> CA $" + seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price'] + "</span>" +
                "<div class='clear'></div>" +
                "</div>");
            price += seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price'];
            $(".checkout_area").html("SUBTOTAL: CA $" + price);
        } else {
            $(obj.attr("rel")).remove();
            obj.attr("rel", "");
             price -= seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price'];
            $(".checkout_area").html("SUBTOTAL: CA $" + price);
        }
    };

    $(".aa").click(function() {
        createNewElem($(this));
    });

$(".desc2 a").live("click", function() {
        var column = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
       var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index(this.parentNode);
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
        $(".seat p span").html($(".desc2").length);
       $(".checkout_area").html("SUBTOTAL: CA $" + price - seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price']);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: we'll need the accompanying HTML to see if this makes sense

Comment: http://rashouse.am/hamal/ticket.php example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t=  price - seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price'];
$(".checkout_area").html("SUBTOTAL: CA $" + t );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what is going wrong from your question, but you could try a `parseFloat` on both values -

```
$(".desc2 a").live("click", function() {
        var column = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
       var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index(this.parentNode);
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
        $(".seat p span").html($(".desc2").length);
       $(".checkout_area").html("SUBTOTAL: CA $" + parseFloat(price) - parseFloat(seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price']);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: $(".desc2 a").live("click", function() {
        var column = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
        var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index(this.parentNode);
        $(".checkout_area").html("SUBTOTAL: CA $" + price - seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price']);
        return false;
    });
it's dos'nt work $(".checkout_area").html("SUBTOTAL: CA $" + price - seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price']);
and what do parseFloat

Comment: but can you explain what makes parseFloat?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing arithmetic with non-numeric string expressions. 
Do something like

```
 var t=  price - seatlist['seats'][column][row]['price'];
 $(".checkout_area").html("SUBTOTAL: CA $" + t );
```

Edit
After looking at your code with firebug it seems that the row col calculation results in undefined elements in the seatlist array. I added one seat and tried to remove it. The element it tries to subtract is undefined in the seat list. i.e. in my case {col=3 row=1 seatlist['seats'][3][1]['price'] = undefined} according to Firebug.
So the primary problem is not in the calculation line (although the reply stands if you want to do correct arithmetic).
I would suggest using Firebug or the Chrome developer tools. After all we cant debug your code for you..